# show single textview contains text in 3 lines with pointswise

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I want to show 3 lines of text in one textview like below? how?

1. first
2. second
3. three is a very big line
   which should be like this.

how can we acheive this? I know we can use all linear layouts to set these textviews in tabular form. but I am thinking to do in a simple way using one textview instead of multiple textviews :P .

Answer (score 0):

Very simple,
enter text in setText function like this,

```
textView.setText("1. xxxxx \n 2.yyyyyyy \n 3.zzzzzzz");
```

this will add 3 lines in output screen. so **\n** is the solution, please mark as correct answer.

Comment: the line 3 should come exactly in two lines where second line should exactly below the starting word of the first line.

Comment: Do you want me to design that logic for you, i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this cleanly with StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("1) Lorem ipsum\n");
builder.append("2) Lorem ipsum\n");
builder.append("3) Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae");

textView.setText(builder.toString());
```